# Titanium XMPP: Send message

Tags: titanium, xmpp, appcelerator

I want to implement a chat application using xmpp in titanium, I started with this example https://github.com/jmartin82/titanium-xmpp.

Now I can connect to my server OpenFire and receive message yet I have problem with sending message.

It give me this errors:

[ERROR] :  function n(){Ti.API.log("handleMessage"),i("tiservice@myhost","Test text")}
[ERROR] :  >>>TypeError: undefined is not a function

Is there any body can give me some help, I will be so appreciated.
Thanks